# Positioning jquery ui dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

How to position jquery ui dialog box with respect to a div element inside the body?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this might get you the idea how to do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="one" class="divs"></div>
<div id="two" class="divs"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.divs {
    float: left;
    height: 48px;
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #55f;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $div = $('#two');
    var left = $div.offset().left;
    var top= $div.offset().top;
    $('<p>Some dialog</p>').dialog({position: [left + 20, top + 20]});
});
```

Here is the link to [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ihusnjak/UWxyH/).

jQuery [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset)() returns element postion relative to document, while [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)() returns relative to offset parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery position function](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or [jQuery UI one](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position)

```
$('#dialog').position({of: $('#your_div')});
```

Comment: You beat me to it! :) Demos of this can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/offset/ shows how to get coordinates of a div element. but direct usage might not be enough as this depends on layout structure (floats, margins, etc).